# How can i make in vue devtools to show errors?

Tags: vue.js

I have install Vue Devtootls but each time I have errors it doesn't show in the console I see o laracast they have like [vue: warn] and the error. I put this code but nothing.

```
catch(function(error){ console.log(error.message); });
   }
```

Comment: Warnings only show in the console if you use a non-production (non-minified) version of Vue.

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding on vue-devtools, vue-devtools is a browser extension used as a debugging tool. You can check your components, events and more information via it. Please have a look at its [introduction](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) on GitHub.

[image: vue-devtools]

On the other hand, messages like `[vue: warn] ...` are produced by Vue itself. The reason that you didn't get the messages is simply because you used `vue.min.js` instead of `vue.js`, I think. Save following code as a html file and then open it in chrome. You should be able to see the warning message in Chrome's console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Vue test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <div id="app">
    <span>{{ message }}</span>
    <component1></component1>
  </div>
  <script>
    // Vue.component('component1', {
    //   template: '<button>{{ message }}</button>',
    //   data: function() {
    //     return {
    //       message: 'I am a test button'
    //     };
    //   }
    // });
    var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'hello'
      },
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: vue-warn]